# Ajax PHP login module

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this login module (a modal that pops up for logging in/registering). Well, I'm not not really that good with php and a newbie in ajax. To be able to login, it should call the *function loginAjax* in **login-register.php** but I think its conflicting with the php I've used on the code below.

**HERE THE CODE I'VE BEEN USING BEFORE TO BE ABLE TO LOG IN**

```
<div class="form loginBox">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="memberemail" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="memberemail"/>
        <input id="memberpassword" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="memberpassword"/>
        <input class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginAjax()" name="memberlogin"/>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['memberlogin'])) {
    $memberemail = $memberpassword = $error = "";
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $memberemail = clean_input($_POST['memberemail']);
        $memberpassword = clean_input($_POST['memberpassword']);
    }

    if(empty($memberemail) || empty($memberpassword)) {
        $error = "Please enter your Username and Password!";
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users
                WHERE email='$memberemail'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $user = mysql_num_rows($res);

        if($user['blocked']=='YES') {
            $error = "Your Account has been blocked. Please contact us for more info";
        }
        else {                                                  
            if($user == 1) {
                $_SESSION['current_user'] = $memberemail;
                header("location: /user_cpanel/index.html");
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $error = "Wrong Username and Password";
            }
        }
    }

    if($error){
        echo '<div class="error"><p>' . $error . '</p></div>';
    }
}
?>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CONFLICTING CODE: login-register.js**

```
function showRegisterForm(){
    $('.loginBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.registerBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.login-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.register-footer').fadeIn('fast');
        });
        $('.modal-title').html('Register with');
    }); 
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');

}
function showLoginForm(){
    $('#loginModal .registerBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.loginBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.register-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.login-footer').fadeIn('fast');    
        });

        $('.modal-title').html('Login with');
    });       
     $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html(''); 
}

function openLoginModal(){
    showLoginForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');    
    }, 230);

}
function openRegisterModal(){
    showRegisterForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');    
    }, 230);

}

function loginAjax(){

    $.post( "/login", function( data ) {
            if(data == 1){
                window.location.replace("index.php");            
            } else {
                 shakeModal(); 
            }
        });

}

function shakeModal(){
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');
             $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Invalid email/password combination");
             $('input[type="password"]').val('');
             setTimeout( function(){ 
                $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake'); 
    }, 1000 ); 
}
```

Comment: Please explain. What do you mean, the codes conflict with each other?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have already updated the question

Comment: This is so messy! An seams really insecure. there is some information missing.  the data you post? go straight to that php file?? First you should try to debug and echo $username in your php file to see if your $post from ajax are set. i suspect that data is sent as an array to php. But i cant tell you much more

Comment: You can't use `header` after you've outputted data to the browser (header("location: /user_cpanel/index.html");) the same apply for session